# Нужно экспортировать улицы из любой онлайн карты

Tags: python, gis

Есть задача дёргать определённые улицы/трассы/шоссе по имени из любой онлайн карты и экспортировать в формат kml, .tab и т.п. Соответственно полученные координаты должны быть по всей длине улицы. Из инструментов желательно обойтись Python. В какую сторону копать, есть ли решения такой задачи?

Comment: у osm есть исходники карты в открытом доступе. отфильтруй объекты

Comment: Да, есть идеи. Вы можете нанять программиста для этой работы, платя ему за каждую добавленную карту/формат.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Геокодер. Правда, геокодеры гугла и яндекса до недавнего времени не предоставляли ломаную геометрию (только охват), так что придется смотреть в сторону OSM.

Например, можно развернуть у себя локальную копию геокодера Nominatim, и искать там все, что угодно... Или использовать онлайн-версию, но там есть ограничение на количество запросов. Да и сами создатели рекомендуют использовать Nominatim локально, если планируется большое количество запросов